# Why can't jQuery update array data before ajax post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am trying to create an array and get all values of a form submission and put them in that array. I need to do this because during the .each function of this code I must do additional encryption to all the values per client. This is a form with hundreds of fields that are changing. So it must be an array to work. I tried to do following and several other types like it in jQuery but no dice. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Edit: Posted my working solution. Thanks for the help.
Edit 2: Accept sabithpocker's answer as it allowed me to keep my key names.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kv9U3/6/

Comment: It's a good idea not to leave the jsfiddle link in a comment and instead post it in the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var inputArray = {};

//jQuery(this).serializeArray() = [{name: "field1", value:"val1"}, {name:field2...}...]

jQuery(this).serializeArray().each(function(index, value) {
    inputArray[value.name] = encrypt(value.value);
});

//now inputArray = [{name: "field1", value:"ENCRYPTED_val1"}, {name:field2...}...]

//now to form the POST message
postMessages = [];
$(inputArray).each(function(i,v){
    postMessages.push(v.name + "=" + v.value);
});
postMessage = postMessages.join('&');
```

Chack [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to see the JSON array format.

http://jsfiddle.net/kv9U3/

So clearly the issue is that `this` in your case is not the array as you suppose. Please clarify what `this` pointer refers to, or just verify yourselves by doing a `console.log(this)`

As you updated your answer, in your case `this` pointer refers to the form you submitted, how do you want to iterate over the form? what are you trying to achieve with the each?

## UPDATE

working fiddle with capitalizing instead of encrypting

http://jsfiddle.net/kv9U3/6/

```
$('#x').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputArray = [];
    console.log(jQuery(this).serializeArray());
    jQuery(jQuery(this).serializeArray()).each(function (index, value) {
        item = {};
        item[value.name] = value.value.toUpperCase();
        inputArray[index] = item;
    });
    console.log(inputArray);
    postMessages = [];
    $(inputArray).each(function (i, v) {
        for(var k in v)
            postMessages[i] = k + "=" + v[k];
        console.log(i, v);
    });
    postMessage = postMessages.join('&');

    console.log(postMessage);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Posted full source to the script in the original post.

Comment: Are you trying to get values of `input` elements in `form` or so?

Comment: I was under the impression that jQuery(this) is my forms post array.

Comment: Firebug returns this error

 jQuery(...).serializeArray(...).each is not a function

Comment: You can check the docs of `serializeArray` in jQuery API docs, as linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `#cja_form` won't list its fields using `each`. You can use `serialize()` instead:

```
inputArray = jQuery(this).serialize();
```

Further edition, if you need to edit each element, you can use this:

```
var input = {};

$(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    input[element.attr('name')] = element.val();
});
```

#### Full code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $("#cja_form").submit(function(event){
        $("#submitapp").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#cja_status").html('<div class="cja_pending">Please wait while we process your application.</div>');

        var input = {};

        $(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
            var element = $(this);
            input[element.attr('name')] = element.val();
        });

        $.post('../wp-content/plugins/coffey-jobapp/processes/public-form.php', input)
        .success(function(result){
            if (result.indexOf("success") === -1) {
                $("#submitapp").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#cja_status").html('<div class="cja_fail">'+result+'</div>');
            }
            else {
                page = document.URL;

                if (page.indexOf('?') === -1) {
                    window.location = page + '?action=success';
                }
                else { 
                    window.location = page + '&action=success';
                }
            }
        })
        .error(function(){
            $("#submitapp").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#cja_status").html('<div class="cja_fail"><strong>Failed to submit article! Check your internet connection.</strong></div>');
        });

        event.preventDefault(); 
        event.returnValue = false;

        return false;
    });
});
```

---

Original answer:

There are no associative arrays in javascript, you need a hash/object:

```
var input = {};

jQuery(this).each(function(k, v){
    input[k] = v;
});
```

Comment: Tried it with no luck. I put the rest of my script up.

Comment: I used serialize() prior before submission but now I HAVE to be able to modify the values client side before it goes over the network. I took it out thinking after the array is made you would submit that and not have to serialize again.

Comment: That is how my script was before. I need to do an .each loop and mod each value.

Comment: Updated my answer, the trick is to find any fields that generate a `POST` variable: `$(this).find('input, select, textarea')`

Comment: The problem with that is I use radio boxes, and all sorts of stuff too. Also modding the value that way mods the content to be gibberish in the text fields, so if they got an error return they would have to redo the form again. This is why I elected to do an array. As a safe way to just run down the POST array list and put it in an array made for manipulation and submission.

Comment: Keep in mind, I am completely blind to the elements the client puts on their form. Even my PHP script depends on getting a list of the Array values. (Which works fine there.)

Comment: Then your description is incomplete mate, it's better to specify these restrictions in the question. Now I don't really know where you extract your info from, and what you want the variables for

Comment: Well in PHP $POST is an array. So doing foreach in PHP does this for breaking this data down for DB entry. I would figure this would have a jQuery method as well.

Comment: You mean you'd like to create an array of variables from your form? then use `$(<the form>).find(<all field types you can think of>).each(...)` which turns out to be `$(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){ <use $(this).attr('name') and $(this).val()> })`. If you are using `input[type=file]` then the AJAX call won't work

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working solution. In this example it adds cat to all the entries and then sends it to the PHP page as an array. From there I access my array via $_POST['data']. I found this solution on http://blog.johnryding.com/post/1548511993/how-to-submit-javascript-arrays-through-jquery-ajax-call

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    jQuery("#cja_form").submit(function(event){
        jQuery("#submitapp").attr("disabled","disabled");
        jQuery("#cja_status").html('<div class="cja_pending">Please wait while we process your application.</div>');
        var data = [];
        jQuery.each(jQuery(this).serializeArray(), function(index, value) {
            data[index] = value.value + "cat";
        });
            jQuery.post('../wp-content/plugins/coffey-jobapp/processes/public-form.php', {'data[]': data})
            .success(function(result){
                if (result.indexOf("success") === -1) {
                    jQuery("#submitapp").removeAttr('disabled');
                    jQuery("#cja_status").html('<div class="cja_fail">'+result+'</div>');
                    } else {
                        page = document.URL;
                        if(page.indexOf('?') === -1) {
                            window.location = page+'?action=success';
                    } else { 
                        window.location = page+'&action=success';
                    }
                }
                })
                .error(function(){
                        jQuery("#submitapp").removeAttr('disabled');
                        jQuery("#cja_status").html('<div class="cja_fail"><strong>Failed to submit article! Check your internet connection.</strong></div>');
                });

        event.preventDefault(); 
        event.returnValue = false;

    });
});
```

Comment: sabithpocker had a better solution. This works but you lose your key names. :(